# Redmine Plugin: adding columns to Redmine-built-in existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

With Rails, adding columns is easy as this link:

[Ruby on Rails: adding columns to existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259687/ruby-on-rails-adding-columns-to-existing-database#)

With Redmine Plugin, adding columns for plugin's table seems OK as this link:
http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/39008

But in my Redmine Plugin, I want to add columns to Redmine's built-in table (for example, I want to add a column named 'my_own_syntax' to "queries" table). Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add migrations to your plugin create them under

```
your_newplugin_folder
|- db
   |- migrate
      |-01_fancy_migration.rb
```

Use numeration for migration files(in filenames but not in class names)

execute em with: `rake redmine:plugins:migrate`

Answer (score 2):

it is just a new migration

```
class AddMyOwnSyntaxToQueries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :queries, :my_own_syntax, :text
  end
end
```